# Internal subdomain to folder redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to create folders on the fly, but make it seem like I am creating subdomains on the fly using mod_rewrite. e.g.

Create "john" folder using PHP

```
www.example.com/john/
```

Then be able to access whatever I put in there at:

```
john.example.com
```

Thank you in advance,

Kris

Comment: Hi I'd like to do something like this potentially did you get this working?

Comment: I haven't go this working yet.  I am switching over to a Plesk system soon, which will allow greater control over my server.  Once I figure it out I will post the tutorial on my blog and answer this question with the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to configure your server to accept any subdomain for your domain `example.com` and redirect it to your virtual host that as well has to accept any subdomain. After that, you can use the following rule to rewrite that subdomain internally to a folder with the same name:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning external maps to recognize invalid subfolders/subdomains :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I really don't know how to do any of this... First, the mod_rewrite code you gave me, where would that go in relation to my folder structure in the original question. Second, how would I do the configuration to my server to accept any subdomain?  As you can tell I'm at the early stages of using mod_rewrite and I need a little help.

Thank you Gumbo

Comment: Considering that you might want to ask your question on serverfault.com

Comment: To accept the sub-domain (it's really just a hostname), that part goes in your DNS zone. The mod_rewrite rules go in your Apache configuration for the virtual host, which also needs ServerAlias *.example.com.