# Rewrite folder to subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm currently building a large scale website that allows each profile page to be it's own unique sub-domain. I was wondering how would I do this using an .htaccess and mod_rewrite?

For example:

Turn this: `http://example.com/profile/userid`
into: `http://userid.example.com`

Comment: With mod_rewrite, the correct question is, how to rewrite http://userid.example.com into http://example.com/profile/userid, as the subdomains will be entered or linked.
Knowing this, your question is a duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961963/internal-subdomain-to-folder-redirect

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, if you are using wildcard DNS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile/%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: What exactly do these rewrite rules accomplish?

Comment: when userid.example.com/foobar is requested, it will show the content of example.com/profile/userid/foobar

Comment: Awesome, one more thing, will this affect any preexisting sub-domains? aka 'real' sub-domains?

Comment: If there are other subdomains on the same host they will be affected, so you need to exclude them in this rule like `www.example.com` above. (see edit)

Comment: AWSOME. ty so much. exactly what i was looking for ... little modification  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /zzzz-wildcard/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]