# How to write a htaccess file to wildcard folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, directory, wildcard

I'm trying to redirect all my folders (using a wildcard) to their subdomain. For example:

> www.mywebsite.com/folder1 to folder1.mywebsite.com/
>   www.mywebsite.com/folder2 to folder2.mywebsite.com/
>   www.mywebsite.com/folder3 to folder3.mywebsite.com/

Now without writing a rule for each one of them, is there a way to redirect them all to their respective subdomain?

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

But it gives me an internal error 500

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725973/rewrite-folder-to-subdomain-with-htaccess

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but that example doesn't really work for me. I tried
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]

But it gives me an internal error 500

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the rules from looping, use a condition to first check if the `/%1/$1` actually exists, **or** that the URI doesn't already start with `%1`

So:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

The `!^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1` expression groups the first folder in the URI, and backreferences it with `\1`. If those are equal, then the first folder in the URI is `%1` which is backreferenced to the previous match `(\w+)`.

Comment: Good point. I believe the about solution that I posted would work if the files were stored in the correct place, but that is most likely not the case. This solution is more elegant and thorough.