# How to write a htaccess file to wildcard 2 level folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

How to rewrite this

www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder1 to folder1.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder2 to folder2.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder3 to folder3.mywebsite.com/

Comment: What is document root of `folder1.mywebsite.com` at present?

Comment: the folder1 is auto create by user and empty 

I found this answer

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]

 and it works good but only for 

www.mywebsite.com/folder1 to folder1.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder2 to folder2.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder3 to folder3.mywebsite.com/

But my case i have 2 level folder : www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder1 .....

Comment: This is the link that i saw the solution but it is for on level folder

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373006/how-to-write-a-htaccess-file-to-wildcard-folder-to-subdomain

Mycase is 2 level folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ /folder/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: where should i put this htaccess, in the root or in the folder

Comment: It takes me to home page not subdomain site
Please have a look, this is the url http://pagezon.com/sites/trung

Comment: ANd when i use your htaccess and type http:trung.pagezon.com

It takes me to homepage not to my subdirectory site

Comment: Any more help please?

Comment: It is not real subdomain, it is wildcard subdomain. I enable wildcard for my domain pagezon.com already. And now i would like to redirect each folder in http://pagezon.com/sites/ to subdomain name using that subfolder name. For example, if there is folder http://pagezon.com/sites/folder1 then it will be same as http://folder1.pagezon.com/

Comment: I have other questions ,can you help me that?

Comment: How to rewrite this

www.mywebsite.com/folder/1-folder1 to folder1.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder/2-folder2 to folder2.mywebsite.com/

www.mywebsite.com/folder/3-folder3 to folder3.mywebsite.com/

Comment: If this worked you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer. And for additional question post a new question here.