# htaccess subdomain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

I've searched around and tried a few different ways but can't get this to work.

I don't actually have the subdomains set up, but will have about 30 similar redirects that I need to do.

E.g:

sub-domain.domain.co.uk needs to go to http://www.domain.com/folder/page-name

There will be hyphens in almost every subdomain and every 'page-name', so I'm not sure if this affects the regex formatting.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: that was a mistake, but it still doesn't work if I change it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the %{HTTP_HOST} variable and match it in a RewriteCond, then use a %1 backreference to access it in a rewrite rule.

Searching for "subdomain redirect" on Stack Overflow, it looks like this is exactly what you want: [Internal subdomain to folder redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961963/internal-subdomain-to-folder-redirect)

---

EDIT

The accepted answer in that StackOverflow link above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

In your .htaccess file, put that above whatever rules you have. Obviously, you're going to need to modify `example\.com` to whatever your domain is, and have the proper directories setup in your document root.

Comment: "First you need to configure your server to accept any subdomain for your domain"
To be honest I'm not even sure where I would do this? I use Hostgator, I would assume it's all good from the start.

Comment: You'll have to see Hostgator's tutorials for setting up subdomains. You just need to point all the subdomains that you setup to the same document root.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to actually create loads of subdomains as it will just cause a huge mess with the volume that I want.
I thought it was possible to redirect a 'virtual' subdomain, regardless of whether is has been 'created' in cPanel.

Comment: Like I said, you need to check Hostgator's support, they probably have articles for stuff like this: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/wildcard-dns-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it And after you have that setup, you can use that RewriteRule in the link to do what you want.

Comment: I already spoke to their technical support but they said they didn't know what to do as they don't help with htaccess.

Other RewriteRules work, such as:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Comment: Use the rules in the link in the answer, but you'll want to put them above the ones you have so they get applied first

Comment: Sorry but I still don't know exactly what I'm doing. I have been working with trial and error for well over an hour now.