# Wanting To Make http://test.domain.tld/ go to http://domain.tld/test

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internal subdomain to folder redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961963/internal-subdomain-to-folder-redirect)

I want it to be automatic as I am making this for a URL shortener. I know how to make each one manually, but that won't work for what I need. I know I need something in .htaccess, but I am not experienced with that at all. Does anyone know what to add to get this working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195458/htaccess-subdomain-redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using apache `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).domain.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://domain.tld/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, unless I have to do something special with the .htaccess.

Comment: @user1832336 You need to load the `mod_rewrite` module. What did you get when you tried it?

Comment: How do I load the mod_rewrite module?

Comment: @user1832336 try this: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Im still confused, Ive never used .htaccess before, the only thing I have done was changing the domain.tld to my domain, what else must I add/change for it to work?

Comment: @user1832336 it can be possibly a lot of things. First of all, you need to make sure, apache is configured to read `.htaccess` files - see (AllowOverride)[http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride] - also let me know, what do you see in your browser? Can't help w/o specific information

Answer (score -1):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your `.htaccess` file. Use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to define the redirect rule. Such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.domain\.tld /$1
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The regular expression in the `RewriteRule` *everytimes* does match against REQUEST_URI - so you cant match domain name in this way... the correct solution is in my answer

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, unless I have to do something special with the .htaccess.

Comment: Well it wasn't meant as a copy&paste solution. I just wanted to provide the links in some context.